# Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Failed to open TCP connection to :80 - Authenticated requests fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, auth0, rails-api

After successfully running Rails 6 apps with shared Auth0 login credentials,
I'm building my first Rails 6 + Auth0 API (https://auth0.com/blog/building-secure-apis-with-rails-6-and-auth0/).

I've created a simple server-app named 'chirps', here is the controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
end

class SecuredController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authorize_request
  
    private
  
    def authorize_request
        AuthorizationService.new(request.headers).authenticate_request!
    rescue JWT::VerificationError, JWT::DecodeError
        render json: { errors: ['Not Authenticated'] }, status: :unauthorized
    end
end

class ChirpsController < SecuredController
    # Comment this for a fully private API
    skip_before_action :authorize_request, only: [:index, :show]

    def index
      chirps = Chirp.all
      render json: chirps
    end
  
    def show
      chirp = Chirp.find(params[:id])
      render json: chirp
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      head :not_found
    end
  
    def create
      chirp = Chirp.create!(chirp_params)
      render json: chirp, status: :created
    end
  
    def destroy
      chirp = Chirp.find(params[:id])
      chirp.delete
      head :no_content
    end
  
    private
  
    def chirp_params
      params.permit(:body, :published)
    end
  end
```

THE PROBLEM - Authenticated requests fails:

```
curl -H “Content-Type: application/json” -H “Authorization: bearer $API_TOKEN” -d ‘{“body”:“this is my first chirp!”, “published”:true}’ -X POST http://localhost:3000/chirps
```

Curl response (first part of it):

```
{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"#\u003cErrno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to :80 (Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 80)\u003e","traces":{"Application Trace":[{"exception_object_id":16740,"id":11,"trace":"app/lib/json_web_token.rb:19:in `jwks_hash'"},{"exception_object_id":16740,"id":12,"trace":"app/lib/json_web_token.rb:14:in `block in verify'"},{"exception_object_id":16740,"id":17,"trace":"app/lib/json_web_token.rb:7:in `verify'"}
```

Rails server response:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Failed to open TCP connection to :80 (Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 80)):

app/lib/json_web_token.rb:19:in jwks_hash'** **app/lib/json_web_token.rb:14:in block in verify’
app/lib/json_web_token.rb:7:in verify'** **app/services/authorization_service.rb:20:in verify_token’
app/services/authorization_service.rb:8:in authenticate_request!'** **app/controllers/secured_controller.rb:7:in authorize_request’
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2021:12:54:19 IST] “POST /chirps HTTP/1.1” 500 19247
- -> /chirps
```

My environment is Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS under **WSL2**:

```
PS C:\Users\YOLA> wsl -l -v
NAME STATE VERSION
Ubuntu Running 2
```

Rails Server:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 6.0.3.4 application starting in development http://localhost:3000
```

I'm quite new at this so I don't fully understand why it fails.

Yony

Comment: when you tried `curl http://localhost:3000/chirps` did you get the response `[]` (as per the article) ?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine with unauthenticated requests. Problem starts with requests that needs authentication:

$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]" -d '{"body":"this is my first chirp!", "published":true}' -X POST http://localhost:3000/chirps

I also tried commenting the following line to test an authenticated GET request:


skip_before_action :authorize_request, only: [:index, :show] // with this commented out I get the same error

Comment: Did you try to configure this to code line `config.hosts << ENV['HOST_NAME']` in the development.rb file of the environments folder?

Comment: Hi Andres, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Currently my ENV['HOST_NAME'] is undefined, and I don't have any config.hosts line in my development.rb

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `auth0_domain` secret is set when you are passing it to the rails app.

If the value is empty, it will make your initial string an invalid URL, i.e. `"https://#{Rails.application.secrets.auth0_domain}/.well-known/jwks.json"` turns into `"https:///.well-known/jwks.json"`.

In [my case](https://masahiro.me/2021/01/auth0-errnoeconnrefused-failed-to-open-tcp-connection-to-443/) I was using an empty environment variable, which returned `nil`:

```
ENV['AUTH0_DOMAIN']
=> nil
```

Hope this answer helps you!

Comment: Thanks! That's not the problem, my ENV['AUTH0_DOMAIN'] is properly set to my auth0 account domain '<account_name>.us.auth0.com'. I define it in development.rb, along with my client_id and client_secret.